# In-order traversal in BST-Ocaml

Tags: recursion, ocaml

I'm working with a polymorphic binary search tree with the standard following type definition:

```
type tree =
    Empty 
  | Node of int * tree * tree (*value, left sub tree, right sub tree*);;
```

I want to do an in order traversal of this tree and add the values to a list, let's say. I tried this:

```
let rec in_order tree =
  match tree with 
  Empty -> []
  | Node(v,l,r) -> let empty = [] in in_order r@empty;
v::empty;
in_order l@empty
;;
```

But it keeps returning an empty list every time. I don't see why it is doing that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you're working with recursion you need to always reason as follows:

- How do I solve the easiest version of the problem?
- Supposing I have a solution to an easier problem, how can I modify it to solve a harder problem?

You've done the first part correctly, but the second part is a mess.

Part of the problem is that you've not implemented the thing you said you want to implement. You said you want to do a traversal and *add the values to a list*.  OK, so then the method should take a list somewhere -- the list you are adding to. But it doesn't.  So let's suppose it does take such a parameter and see if that helps. Such a list is traditionally called an *accumulator* for reasons which will become obvious.

As always, get the signature right first:

```
let rec in_order tree accumulator =
```

OK, what's the easy solution?  If the tree is empty then adding the tree contents to the accumulator is simply the identity:

```
match tree with
| Empty -> accumulator
```

Now, what's the recursive case? We suppose that we have a solution to some smaller problems. For instance, we have a solution to the problem of "add everything on one side to the accumulator with the value":

```
| Node (value, left, right) -> 
  let acc_with_right = in_order right accumulator in
  let acc_with_value = value :: acc_with_right in
```

OK, we now have the accumulator with all the elements from one side added. We can then use that to add to it all the elements from the other side:

```
  in_order left acc_with_value
```

And now we can make the whole thing implement the function you tried to write in the first place:

```
let in_order tree =
  let rec aux tree accumulator =
    match tree with
    | Empty -> accumulator
    | Node (value, left, right) -> 
      let acc_with_right = aux right accumulator in
      let acc_with_value = value :: acc_with_right in
      aux left acc_with_value in
  aux tree []
```

And we're done.

Does that all make sense?  You have to (1) actually implement the exact thing you say you're going to implement, (2) solve the base case, and (3) assume you can solve smaller problems and combine them into solutions to larger problems. That's the pattern you use for all recursive problem solving.

Comment: `in_order (Node (1, Node (2, Empty, Empty), Node (3, Empty, Empty)))` should return `[2; 1; 3]`, not `[1; 2; 3]`.

Comment: @AntonTrunov: Whoops, I wrote preorder, didn't I?  Easy fix.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem boils down to this. The `@` operator returns a new list that is the concatenation of two other lists. It doesn't modify the other lists. In fact, nothing ever modifies a list in OCaml. Lists are immutable.

So, this expression:

```
r @ empty
```

Has no effect on the value named `empty`. It will remain an empty list. In fact, the value `empty` can never be changed either. Variables in OCaml are also immutable.

You need to imagine constructing and returning your value without modifying lists or variables.

When you figure it out, it won't involve the `;` operator. What this operator does is to evaluate two expressions (to the left and right), then return the value of the expression at the right. It doesn't combine values, it performs an action and discards its result. As such, it's not useful when working with lists. (It is used for imperative constructs, like printing values.)

If you thought about using `@` where you're now using `;`, you'd be a lot closer to a solution.